# JSONArray to string array

Tags: java, json

It looks like too much boilterplate to convert a json array to string[]. Is there any simpler and elegant way?

```
final JSONArray keyArray = input.getJSONArray("key");
String[] keyAttributes = new String[keyArray.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < keyArray.length(); i++) {
    keyAttributes[i] = keyArray.getString(i);
}
```

Comment: Assuming org.json.JSONArray. Nope, that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`gson`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It's got a much friendlier API than `org.json`.

[Collections Examples](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) (from the [User Guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection<Integer> ints = Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);

//(Serialization)
String json = gson.toJson(ints); ==> json is [1,2,3,4,5]

//(Deserialization)
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
//ints2 is same as ints
```

Comment: Thanks. int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class);  something like this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are right! Even [@Sean Patrick Floyd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779595/2153244) answer is too much boilterplate to covert a JSON array to string[] or any other type of array class. Rather here is what I find to be elegant:

```
JsonArray jsonArray = input.getAsJsonArray("key");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] output = gson.fromJson(jsonArray , String[].class)
```

**NOTE 1**: `JsonArray` must be an array of strings, for the above example, without any property names. Eg:

```
{key:["Apple","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Guava"]}
```

**Note 2:** `JsonObject` class used above is from `com.google.gson` library and not the `JSONObject` class from `org.json` library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any built-in method that do this and I think it is the simplest way

Here is [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array) that will help you

Comment: Even using a 'well known' library would do for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] jsonArrayToStringArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    int arraySize = jsonArray.size();
    String[] stringArray = new String[arraySize];

    for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
        stringArray[i] = (String) jsonArray.get(i);
    }

    return stringArray;
};
```

Comment: person asking the question wants to avoid this and has posted exact same snippet in question.