# Init object with multi-typed array

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

I have got a problem using JSON parser in an android application.
I'm starting with this platform, and would like to:

- get some values (different types) from a JSON API
- init a custom class with theses values easily

So, in the iOS application, I made it with a NSDictionnary to set the values to my class.
Is it possible to do a such thing in Java ?

I have my User class :

```
public class User {
    protected String id;
    protected GregorianCalendar registredAt;
    protected String username;
    protected String email;
    protected Integer score;
    protected Integer bonus;
    protected Integer sessionsOpened;
    protected Integer sessionsWon;
    protected Team team;
    protected String avatar;
}
```

Of course I could create a big constructor with every values...

```
public User(String id, GregorianCalendar registredAt, String username, String email, Integer score, Integer bonus, Integer sessionsOpened, Integer sessionsWon, Team team, String avatar) {
    this.id = id;
    this.registredAt = registredAt;
    ...
}
```

But, to do it, I must manage my JSONObject before to init my User class...
What I would do is to initialize this class with the an array of multi-typed values that I could get from the JSONObject...
( [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array) )

Is it possible ?
What is the best method to get a clean array from a JSONObject or JSONArray ?

If it is not possible, another way could be to create the User directly with the JSONObject...

```
public User(JSONObject attributes) {

}
```

But I would prefer the java array if that is possible.

Thank you in advance,
Bobby.

Comment: Have a look at `java.util.HashMap` - something like `NSDictionary`

Comment: Yeah I just saw it :)

But is it possible to set Objects in a HashMap, as GregorianCalendar or Team (another Class) ?

Comment: Yes, a `Map` can contain any object types as keys and any object types as values, as long as it's declared properly (in the generics sense), e.g. `Map<?,?> data = new HashMap<?,?>();`

Comment: Okay thank you, it's good to know.

I will finally use the jackson library to parse my API Json callbacks.