# Easiest and most efficient way to convert JSONArray to List

Tags: java, json, gson

What is the easiest and most efficient way to convert org.json.JSONArray to List?

Comment: Which do you want?  Easiest or most efficient?  :-)

Comment: Take a for loop and iterate through Json array store in list, is easiest way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)

Comment: FYI, `net.sf.JSONArray` implements `java.util.List`.