# Parsing JSON arrays, in a JSON file, into a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

I have been trying, and struggling, to parse arrays contained in a JSON file, into a Java ArrayList. Could I please have some advise on how to proceed with this? Please find an example JSON Array below:

```
[
  {

    "id": "USER_ID_HERE",
    "dateTime": "DATE_TIME_HERE",
    "message": "WRITE_SOMETHING_MEANINGFUL_HERE",
    "latitude":  27.99999
    "longitude": 26.33333333
  }
]
```

My current Java code can be found below - how can I parse in the array from the JSON file?

```
public class ParseJSON {

ArrayList <Tweet> = new ArrayList <Tweet>();

class Tweet{
public String id;
public String message;
public String dateTime;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
} 

JSONObject js = new JSONObject("tweets");

JSONArray jsarray = js.getJSONArray("tweets");
int size = jsarray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    JSONObject tweet = jsarray.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println("tweet: " + tweet.getString("id"));
    System.out.println("tweet: " + tweet.getString("message"));
    System.out.println("tweet: " + tweet.getString("dateTime"));
    System.out.println("tweet: " + tweet.getDouble("latitude"));
    System.out.println("tweet: " + tweet.getDouble("longitude"));
}

   t = new tweet( tweet.getString("id")) & ( tweet.getString("message")) & ( tweet.getString("datetime")) & ( tweet.getDouble("latitude")) &    ( tweet.getDouble("longitude"));

  Tweet.list.add(t);

 }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: This can be helpfull for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array

Comment: The JSON sample above is an "array" containing an "object".  (See json.org for the syntax.)  It maps to a Java List containing a Map.

Comment: can you specify what is the exception / behavior that you currently have? what are you trying to achive? (print to screen, store in objects.. etc)

Comment: I am unsure how to parse the JSON file into Eclipse - what is the array equivalent of parsing an object (Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("insert file location"));)?

Comment: I will be using the data that is parsed in with Sentiwordnet in order to gather values for tweets, to determine whether they are negative or positive

Comment: An array is an Object.  (Don't confuse Java's Object with JSON's "object".  The former is the mother of all Java classes, the latter is JSON's equivalent of a Java Map.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be pretty close to the required functionality, some issues though:

Firstly, the code you want to execute is not in a method. Try to add a "main" method to your `ParseJSON` class.

Your `Tweet` class doesn't have a custom constructor, so you won't be able to create `Tweet` objects and populate their attributes with a constructor as you attempt to do further down.

Your `ArrayList<Tweet>` member variable doesn't have an identifier.

For:

```
t = new tweet( tweet.getString("id")) & ( tweet.getString("message")) & ( tweet.getString("datetime")) & ( tweet.getDouble("latitude")) &    ( tweet.getDouble("longitude"));
```

You want to do this for each element of the JSON array, so move the line inside your `for` loop. Also, the parameters should be separated by a comma, not an ampersand. You should also use a capital T for `new Tweet` (to refer to the constructor you should have created).

For:

```
Tweet.list.add(t);
```

This currently expects `list` to be a (static) member of `Tweet`. Try changing this to access the name you should have given to your `ArrayList`. This line should also be inside the `for` loop for the same reason as above.

Comment: Just for the record, in Java, empty constructors are not mandatory. Java provides an empty one by default if not defined.

Comment: Indeed, but further down there is an attempt at using a non-default constructor. You're right I will be clearer on that.

Comment: Can't manage to find the piece of code you are talking about, but it was a FYI for the OP nevertheless

Comment: Near the bottom: `t = new tweet( tweet.getString("id")) & ( tweet.getString("message")) & ( tweet.getString("datetime")) & ( tweet.getDouble("latitude")) &    ( tweet.getDouble("longitude"));`

Comment: Oh.. Isn't `tweet` a `JSONObject`?