# Parse the json objects inside json Array in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpclient

I am trying to parse json values into my Android application and put the result in a lisview. There is my JSON result:

```
[
{"dateticket": "12/02/2015",
"description": "kkkkkk",
"etat": "suivi",
"idticket": 32,
"nomfichier": "contrat",
"objet": "contrat",
"priorite": "first"},
{"dateticket": null,
"description": null,
"etat": "en cours",
"idticket": 98,
"nomfichier": "lotfi",
"objet": "contrat",
"priorite": "normale"},
{
"dateticket": null,
"description": null,
"etat": "en cours",
"idticket": 99,
"nomfichier": "lotfi",
"objet": "contrat",
"priorite": "normale"},
]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem?? you can try using 'JsonObject' and 'JsonArray'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this

Make necessary changes.

```
private void OpenparseJson(String stringJson) {
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(stringJson);
        JSONObject jObject = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String s1 = jObject.getString("dateticket");
            String s2 = jObject.getString("description");
            String s3 = jObject.getString("etat");
            String s4 = jObject.getString("idticket");
            String s5 = jObject.getString("nomfichier");
            String s6 = jObject.getString("objet");
            String s7 = jObject.getString("priorite");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create jsonarray and then iterate each jsonobject inside this jsonarray into jsonobject object and the getstring using key of each

```
JsonArray array=new JsonArray(<responsestring>);
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
{
 JsonObject json=array.getJsonObject(i);
 String dateticket= json.getString("dateticket");
 //......etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) that you can follow

Also consider using GSON library to parse JSON data in Java. It removes the need to have loops/if statements etc. whilst parsing. More info on that [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)