# How to fetch data using Json?

Tags: android, json

i get data from the server in the following form.how can i fetch this data from the server using JSON parsing.

```
"\r\nArray\n(\n [0] => Array\n (\n [rewardID] => 1\n [rewardTypeName] => Cash Reward\n [rewardDescription] => Winners are rewarded money\n )\n\n [1] => Array\n (\n [rewardID] => 2\n [rewardTypeName] => In-Kind Reward\n [rewardDescription] => Winners are acknowledged for their performance\n )\n\n [2] => Array\n (\n [rewardID] => 3\n [rewardTypeName] => Products or Services\n [rewardDescription] => Winners are rewarded with a product or service\n )\n\n [3] => Array\n (\n [rewardID] =>
```

Comment: `We are not here for doing u r home work. do by u r self.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)

Comment: if u don't want to give answer then please don't give comments like this..

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
 private JSONObject json;
json = new JSONObject(bunldeString);
            String name = json.getString("name");
            String lname = json.getString("lname");
            String age =json.getString("age");

            String data = "Name ::  " + name + "\Last name :: " + lname + "\nAge::"+age;
            responseTV.setText(data);
```

Change the parameters age,name,lname according to your data.
Cheers!

Comment: i am using 
String json = jParser.makeServiceCall(LOAD_REWARD_TYPE_URL,JSONParser.GET);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
 Log.d("Reward Id",jsonObject.getString(TAG_REWARD_ID));

Comment: did u put your result in the bundleString?

Comment: it working thanks..
now i am having error 'String cannot be converted to Json Object'