# Convert String to array in android from json response

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, type-conversion

I am getting json response in array form like this

```
 ["Monday","Wednesday","Friday"]
```

, but it is not saving as a array in android, I am storing that in a string like this

```
 String daysOfInterest = map.get("daysOfinterest");

 [{"careTypeId":"10","careTypeName":"Vacation Care","daysOfinterest":["Tuesday","Thursday","Saturday"],"childDaysOfInterestId"‌​:"424"},
  {"careTypeId":"10","careTypeName":"Vacation Care","daysOfinterest":["Monday","Wednesday","Friday"],"childDaysOfInterestId":"‌​425"}]
```

this is my response and I am storing that daysofInterest in hashmap...and getting using hashmap

But I want to get that in a array form

Comment: What is the exact response and how are you trying to store it in an array? Post the code that you tried.

Comment: [{"careTypeId":"10","careTypeName":"Vacation Care","daysOfinterest":["Tuesday","Thursday","Saturday"],"childDaysOfInterestId":"424"},{"careTypeId":"10","careTypeName":"Vacation Care","daysOfinterest":["Monday","Wednesday","Friday"],"childDaysOfInterestId":"425"}]     this is my response and I am storing that daysofInterest in hashmap...and getting using hashmap

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the json array into a java array with this

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
   int len = jsonArray.length();
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
} 
String[] myArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

then you can pass the array elements to your map. more info here [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Days[] daysArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Days[].class);
```

[Here](https://github.com/google/gson) is Gson library and [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library) is example.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is useful.

`yourstring` is `["AA", "BB", "CC"]`

```
if (!yourstring.equals("")) {
    String[] type = yourstring
    .replace("[", "")
    .replace("]", "")
    .replace("\"", "")
    .split(",");
}
```