# Displaying data by looping through JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json

I would like to know how to loop through the JSON Array.
Database looks like that:

```
{"Similar": {"Info": [{"Name": "Pulp Fiction", "Type": "movie"}], "Results": [{"Name": "Reservoir Dogs", "Type": "movie"}, {"Name": "Kill Bill", "Type": "movie"}, {"Name": "Jackie Brown", "Type": "movie"}
```

I am using an API call and I want to extract only the titles of the movies so I have e.g. "Reservoir Dogs", "Kill Bill" displayed in the log.

This code extracts "Reservoir Dogs" and shows it in the log:

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray array = response.getJSONObject("Similar").getJSONArray("Results");

                String movie = String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject("Similar").getJSONArray("Results").getJSONObject(0).getString("Name"));

                Log.d("recommendMe", movie);

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
```

Unfortunately, to display all titles I would need to create at least several String variables, ten or twenty. So the question is, how to loop through this array to show all titles in one go?

Comment: You don't loop through JSON. You load and decode the JSON, at which point it ceases to be JSON, and then iterate over the array, assuming it is an array.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array) answer your question?

Comment: JSON is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp:)

**Supose this is your json:**

```
'{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
```

**Send it to an obj:**

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

**Now you can use this way:**

```
alert(obj.name);
alert(obj.age);
```