# How do I Convert JSON Array into ArrayList<ClassType> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

This is my input JSON From which I have to fetch `interLockingGrids` and store it into `ArrayList<ClassType>`. I have searched enough already but didn't find exactly what I want. Is there is any simplest way?

```
{"entity":"MasterGrid",

"data" :"{\"name\":\"MA_Pune\",
\"coordinates\" : [
{\"lat\":18.553449789265677,\"lng\":73.77419574114515},{\"lat\":18.554232972087224,\"lng\":73.77367002817823},{\"lat\":18.556135000463573,\"lng\":73.77144913093571},{\"lat\":18.555148376025496,\"lng\":73.7700973257704},{\"lat\":18.55309341985624,\"lng\":73.77075145899971},{\"lat\":18.5530421437421,\"lng\":73.77312207276918} ] ,
\"interLockingGrids\": [
{\"name\":\"Test1\",\"type\":\"CLUSTER\",\"coordinates\":[{\"lat\":18.555151666563823,\"lng\":73.7700902617189},{\"lat\":18.556135000463573,\"lng\":73.77144913093571},{\"lat\":18.556135000463573,\"lng\":73.77144913093571},{\"lat\":18.556135000463573,\"lng\":73.77144913093571},{\"lat\":18.556135000463573,\"lng\":73.77144913093571},{\"lat\":18.556135000463573,\"lng\":73.77144913093571}],\"isActive\":true,\"colorCode\":\"#D0983C\"} ,
{\"name\":\"Test2\",\"type\":\"CLUSTER\",\"coordinates\":[{\"lat\":18.5530421437421,\"lng\":73.77312207276918},{\"lat\":18.553449789265677,\"lng\":73.77419574114515},{\"lat\":18.55238201763598,\"lng\":73.7743998478852}],\"isActive\":true,\"colorCode\":\"#8E75B7\"}  ] ,

"operation":"GRID_OPERATION",
"description":"Baner_Test",
"submittedBy":"m@abc.com",
"submittedById":4,
"submittedByType":"OPS" }
```

Comment: By googling your title and taking the first result you get already an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Json Array to normal Java Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array)

Answer (score -1):

In a recent project I did something similar:

```
public List<MyType> parseJsonToListOfMyType(String json) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray job = gson.fromJson(json, JsonArray.class);
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyType>>(){}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(job, listType);
    }
```