# How to convert a jsonArray into List<String> Java?

Tags: java, json

I am using openjdk 11 and I am calling an api that is returning content type json. I parsing the response and converting into a string like this ( Need to do it this way as I am expecting responses in different formats/structure):

```
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    try
    {
        responseBody = EntityUtils.toString( entity );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        LOG.error( "Unable to parse response", e );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where response is a **org.apache.http.HttpResponse** type object.

After converting into a string, the response looks like :

```
["abc","bcd","cde"]
```

Now, I was trying to put this into jsonObject or JsonArray as

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
 Arrays.asList(jsonArray).stream().forEach(e-> LOG.info("Connector: " + e));
```

While my **jsonArray** looks good, getting error like :

```
["abc","bcd","cde"] is not an array
```

Question is : **How to convert that jsonArray into a List in Java**    ?

Comment: can you show this API call code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume JSONArray comes from Android. You can just do this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject;
if (jsonArray != null) {
    int len = jsonArray.length();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Source: [Convert Json Array to normal Java list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-list?noredirect=1)

Comment: Have you just copy pasted answer from other SO question instead of commenting this question as a duplicate?

Comment: I do not have permissions to mark as duplicate, so yes. If you believe its a duplicate, please mark it as one.