# Merge multiple string json into one java

Tags: java, json

I have multiple json strings like:

JSON 1:

```
{
"a":"test1",

"b":"test2"
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
"b":"test3",

"c":"test4"
}
```

I want final json as:

```
{
"a":"test1",

"b":["test2","test3"],
"c":"test4"
}
```

How can I do this in java?

Comment: What's the business here? Why b has test2 and then becomes test1, test3? 
why JSON 1 is declared twice? Please update your question, and explain what you want in english not in Json :)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261053/how-to-get-all-the-distinct-values-by-key-inside-stream-java8/58261339#58261339 this will give u some hints

Comment: you seems to need a different behaviour for values creation, i,e if it's the only value use `String` type else use `List`, you'll need to parse the json to objects and then build the result json, merge by custom logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any one of the most popular JSON libraries to achieve this, following sample shows how to merge several JSON string into one by `Jackson`.

I use a `Map<String, Object>` (says *jsonMap*) for the merged JSON string. If the key in all given JSON string is identical, then its value in *jsonMap* will be `String`. Otherwise, its value will be `List<String>`.

**Sample code**

```
List<String> jsonStrList = Arrays.asList("{\"a\":\"test1\",\"b\":\"test2\"}","{\"b\":\"test3\",\"c\":\"test4\"}");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String jsonStr : jsonStrList) {
    Map<String, String> jsonContent = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Map.class);
    jsonContent.forEach((k,v) -> {
        if (jsonMap.containsKey(k)) {
            if (jsonMap.get(k) instanceof String) {
                List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
                content.add(jsonMap.get(k).toString());
                content.add(v);
                jsonMap.put(k, content);
            } else {
                jsonMap.put(k, ((ArrayList) jsonMap.get(k)).add(v));
            }
        } else {
            jsonMap.put(k, v);
        }
    });
}
System.out.println(jsonMap.toString());
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonMap).toString());
```

**Console output**

> {a=test1, b=[test2], c=test4}
>   {"a":"test1","b":["test2","test3"],"c":"test4"}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an API or framework for parsing JSON in java. Then you'll have to iterate over your JSON strings, parse them into key value pairs. Once you have that, I recommend using a Map to store them by key. Here is some Pseudo Code:

```
public class KeyValuePair {
    private String key = null;
    private String value = null;
    // todo create constructor with arguments
    // todo create getters and setters
}

private List<KeyValuePair> parseJSON(String json) {
    List<KeyValuePair> parsed = new ArrayList<>();
    // todo use the JSON API you chose to parse the json string into an ArrayList of KeyValuePair
    return parsed;
}

Map<String, List<String>> results = new HashMap<>();
List<String> jsonStrings = new ArrayList<>();
// todo read your JSON strings into jsonStrings
for (String jsonString : jsonStrings) {
    List<KeyValuePair> pairs = parseJSON(jsonString);
    for (KeyValuePair pair : pairs) {
        List<String> values = results.get(pair.getKey());
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<>();
            results.put(pair.getKey(), values);
        }
        values.add(pair.getValue());
    }
}
// todo you'll have to loop through the map's keys and construct your result JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSONObject class](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf231/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html) to do the operations you need. As I understand you are currently having some Strings. You can create a JSONObject for each of your String using the constructor :

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(String str);
```

Then you can iterate through your JSONObject, do all your checking an construct the new JSON inside a new JSONObject. You have some really nice methods that can be very helfpful for you, but I think the get and put methods would be enough to achieve this merge.