# How do I convert a JsonArray of JsonString to a List of String

Tags: java, json

This question is scoped to The Java API for JSON Processing (JSR 353).

Given a JsonArray whose elements are JsonString, how can I easily convert this to a `List<String>` or `a Set<String>`?  For `Set<String>`, let's assume that the JsonArray contains a unique collection of string values.

Assume I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "name" : "James Johns",
  "street" : "22 Nancy St.",
  "emails" : [
               "james@a.com",
               "james@b.net",
               null,
               ""
             ]
}
```

I want my resulting collection to ignore any null or empty string entries in the emails array.

Let's assume my JsonObject instance has already been created.

```
JsonObject person = <parse the JSON input>;
JsonArray emails = person.get("emails");
```

I keep getting stumped on JsonValue and JsonString and trying to get the actual String value.  If I use the `JsonValue.toString()` and `JsonString.toString()` methods, I get string values that include the double quotes, as if the original JSON was `"\"james@a.com\""`.  I need the string values to be the equivalent JSON value `"james@a.com"`.

Comment: Possible answer to your question: [Convert Json Array to normal Java list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-list).

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that the Java8 technique I described is cleaner and easier to understand that having to null check the array and then use a brute force indexing for loop?  It turns out there is an answer supplied that is similar to mine, but it is pretty far down the list.  I created this post in the hopes it will help new inquiries.  I searched a long time looking for a solution and never found the one you linked.  Thank you for your comment @LHCHIN

Comment: Hi, I just provided a possible solution I found to your QUESTION not to your ANSWER as a reply. And I also agreed that Java 8's solution is better! : )

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, one can easily convert a JsonArray of JsonString to a List like this:

```
JsonObject person = <parse the JSON input>;

List<String> emailList = 
    Optional.ofNullable(person.getJsonArray("emails"))
            .orElse(JsonValue.EMPTY_JSON_ARRAY) // Use an empty list if the property's value was null
            .getValuesAs(JsonString::getString) // Get each JsonString entry as String
            .stream()                           // Turn the collection into a stream for filter/collect
            .filter(email -> email!=null && !email.isEmpty())  // Exclude any null/empty entries
            .collect(Collectors.toList());                     // Create the List
```

- The `ofNullable/orElse`combination guarantees I get a JsonArray back, even if that array is empty, thus avoiding any Null Pointer Exception considerations.
- The `getValuesAs(JsonString::getString)` is a JsonArray method that returns a List by applying the `JsonString.getString()` method to each returned JsonString.  The `JsonString.getString()` method returns the string value "james@a.com" instead of the "\"james@a.com\"" value that the `JsonString.toString()` method returns.
- The `stream()` method turns the collection into a sequential stream that we can use to filter and collect members of the original collection.
- The `filter()` method applies the Predicate `email -> email!=null && !email.isEmpty()` to each entry in the stream, throwing out any null entries or entries that are empty strings.
- And finally, the `collect()` method collects the filtered entries into the specified collection type.

To obtain a `Set<String>`, change the `.collect()` to use:

```
.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Once you get accustomed to the Java 8 mechanics, this approach provides a concise, easy to read and understand technique for manipulating collections without the more complicated approach of null/empty checking and using for loops.